# java-servlet request.getParameterValues()

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have an array which holds other arrays I am passing as a parameter. I am using `request.getParameterValues()` to get the parameter but the problem is only the original array is coming in the array format. The arrays inside the array are being converted to string. Is there another way to send and receive multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: @mayan: Are the arrays inside coming as comma (,) separated  strings??

Comment: Where is the code? Are you sure the content of the main array is an array before forwarding the request? Please let us see how you store, forward and get the array.

Comment: yes the arrays inside aomming as comma(,) separated values i dont want to use the split..

Comment: Did you find any way to resolve this problem without using split?

Answer (score 28):

If you are using GET method you must build query like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/myServlet/?habits=Movies&habits=Writing&habits=Singing
```

If you are using POST method you must use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content Type or just use Post method in your HTML form. For example:

```
 <form method="post">
 Habits :
    <input type="checkbox" name="habits" value="Reading">Reading
    <input type="checkbox" name="habits" value="Movies">Movies
    <input type="checkbox" name="habits" value="Writing">Writing
    <input type="checkbox" name="habits" value="Singing">Singing
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Then in both cases in your servlet:

```
String[] outerArray=request.getParameterValues('habits');
your array will be filled with separated values:

//["Writing","Singing"]
```

Answer (score 2):

if the inner arrays are coming as comma(,) separated  then try the below code

```
String[] outerArray=request.getParameterValues('parameterName');

String[] innerArray=outerArray[0].split(",");
```

Dynamically, you could do this and use different `String[]` to store the data or use an `ArrayList` of `String[]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {

           String[] innerArray=outerArray[i].split(",");         
        }
```

Comment: This is the problem i dont want use the split, since my array values also have some patterns like ,.-etc

Comment: @mayan: Then there is only one way to workaround instead of sending inner arrays...send strings separated by characters like `#$#` or `$$$` or `###` some pattern that does not come up in the array and then use `split("the pattern")`;

Comment: Well for the time being this could be one of doing that...there is no problem in trying it out if it helps....instead of filling out an array in `Javascript` you append a string with each value ending with a specific pattern